# PHP add minutes to MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

```
use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime;

$date = new UTCDateTime($val * 1000); // 1659356187861
```

How can I do this if I want to subtract or add 5 minutes from this $date variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php

Since the `UTCDateTime` constructor accepts a `DateTime` object you can start with that, do the modifications, then create the `UTCDateTime` object using the `DateTime`:

```php
use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime;

// Start with @ to use a timestamp then add 5 minutes
$date = (new \DateTime('@' . $val))->modify('+5 minute');

$mongoDate = new UTCDateTime($date);
```